# Write a program to find the difference between Simple Interest and Compound Interest when Principal, Rate and Time are given

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class SICI{
    public static void main( double rate, double time, double principal ){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        double s,c,d,ib;
        s= principal*rate*time/100.0;
        System.out.println("SI:" +s);
        ib=(1+(rate/100.0));
        c=principal*(Math.pow(ib,time)-1);
        System.out.println("CI:" +c);
        d=(float) c-s;
        System.out.println("Difference:" + d);
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

this is my solution, but when trying to run, it's showing:

```
Main method not found in the file, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args)
```

can anyone please help?

Comment: You need to declare the java method main too `public static void main(String[]args){`

Comment: Welcome to the site. Dren is right. You can not change the signature of the main method. More info and other possible errors here -> https://www.journaldev.com/12552/public-static-void-main-string-args-java-main-method

Comment: but you see i working just fine in BLueJ, I am having this problem only with VScode.

Comment: Then BlueJ is doing something special/unusual. The main method in Java has a very specific signature it must match.

Comment: i understand...

Comment: The code you write within BlueJ is pure Java. But it **does** implement some features (such as different main method signatures like this) that are not part of standard Java.

Comment: More specifically: BlueJ lets you directly launch any static method and doesn't require you to have a traditional `public static void main(String[] args)` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the main method's signature. You have to keep that as it is,

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ...
}
```

What you can do is, write another static method with your required parameters and call it from the main function.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double rate, time, principal;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter rate: ");
    rate = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter time: ");
    time = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter principal: ");
    principal = sc.nextDouble();
    double diff = calculateDifference(rate,time,principal);
    System.out.println("difference: "+ diff);
}
```

In the calculateDifference method, pass the parameters and do the job:

```
public static double calculateDifference (double rate, double time, double principal)
{
    double s, c, d, ib;
    s = principal * rate * time / 100.0;
    System.out.println ("SI:" + s);
    ib = (1 + (rate / 100.0));
    c = principal * (Math.pow (ib, time) - 1);
    System.out.println ("CI:" + c);
    d = (float) c - s;
    return d;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with the signature of the main method

```
import java.util.*;
public class SICI{
```

That I have fixed

```
public static void main(String[] args){
```

First Input

```
System.out.print("Enter Rate: ");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
double rate = in.nextDouble();
```

Second Input

```
System.out.print("Enter Time: "); 
Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in);
double time = in.nextDouble();
```

Third Input

```
System.out.print("Enter Principal: "); 
Scanner in3 = new Scanner(System.in);
double principal = in.nextDouble();
```

Calculation

```
double s,c,d,ib;
s= principal*rate*time/100.0;
System.out.println("SI:" +s);
ib=(1+(rate/100.0));
c=principal*(Math.pow(ib,time)-1);
System.out.println("CI:" +c);
d=(float) c-s;
System.out.println("Difference:" + d);

}
```

}

Comment: Just code.  No explanation.  I wouldn't upvote it.